# Run different java code depending on the os (Windows/Android)

Tags: java, android, operating-system

I have a project which it would be nice to contains commun code between Java on Windows and Java on Android. In fact I'm trying to instantiate corect class depending on my OS.

The problem I'm facing of is I don't know how to have Android code in Java on Windows without error...

In a perfect world I would like to use my class like this :

```
 AClass class = Factory.getInstance("AClass");
```

And the Factory will return a new instance of the correct class depending on the OS the programm is runing on.

I don't know if I'm understandable..

Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 0):

System.getProperty("os.name") gives you the operating system that you work on.

But java in Android and java in Windows are really different cases.